Analytic Function with Integral
Let $m(t)$ be a continuous complex-valued function on the unit interval $[0, 1]$, and define  $$F(z) = \displaystyle\int_{0}^{1} \dfrac{m(t)}{(t-z)^{2}}\mathrm{d}t$$.
Prove that $F$ is analytic on $\mathbb{C}\backslash [0,1]$ and $$F'(z) = \displaystyle\int_{0}^{1} \dfrac{2m(t)}{(t-z)^{3}}\mathrm{d}t$$
I try to use the the $\epsilon - \delta$ definition to prove this and come up with this:
$$\left|\dfrac{F(z)-F(z_{0})}{z-z_{0}}-F'(z_{0})\right|=\left|\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1} m(t) \left[\dfrac{2t-z-z_{0}}{(t-z)^2(t-z_{0})^{2}}-\dfrac{2}{(t-z_{0})^{3}}\right]\mathrm{d}t\right|$$
I want to control $|t-z|, |t-z_{0}|$ by using $$d(z) = \min_{t\in [0,1]} |t-z|$$ for $z\in\mathbb{C}\backslash [0,1]$ so that I can have $|z-z_{0}|< \dfrac{d(z_{0})}{2}$ or even smaller like $\dfrac{d(z_{0})}{3}, \dfrac{d(z_{0})}{4},...$.
Please don't use the Cauchy Integral's Formula.
Can anyone help me please? Thank you so much

Try the Leibniz rule https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

By a basic result in Rudin's RCA, the function $G(z) = \displaystyle\int_{0}^{1} \dfrac{m(t)}{(t-z)}\mathrm{d}t$ is analytic in $\mathbb C \setminus [0,1]$ and $G'(z)=F(z)$.

Observe that
$$ \frac{2t-z-z_0}{(t-z)^2(t-z_0)^2} - \frac{2}{(t-z_0)^3} = \frac{3t-2z-z_0}{(t-z_0)^3(t-z)^2} (z-z_0) $$
So
$$\left|\int_0^1 m(t) \frac{2t-z-z_0}{(t-z_0)^2(t-z)^2} - \frac{2t}{(t-z_0)^3 }dt\right| \leq \left(\int_0^1 |m(t)| \frac{|3t-2z-z_0|}{(t-z_0)^3(t-z)^2}dt \right) |z-z_0|$$
Choosing a small ball $U$ of $z_0$ in $\mathbb{C}\setminus [0,1]$ of radius $\delta$, we can then bound the right side of the above by $C |z-z_0|$, for some constant $C$ that depends only on $m$, $z_0$ and $\delta$.
EDIT:
I will add more details on how to get that bound. First note that
$$|3t-2z-z_0| \leq 3t +2|z| + |z_0| \leq 3t + 2|z-z_0|+3|z_0| \leq 3(t+|z_0|) + 2\delta$$
We can shrink the ball $U$ so that $\epsilon:=\inf_{z \in U, t\in [0,1]} |t-z|>0$. We then get that for any $z \in U$,
$$\left(\int_0^1 |m(t)| \frac{|3t-2z-z_0|}{(t-z_0)^3(t-z)^2}dt \right) |z-z_0| \leq \left(\sup_{t\in[0,1]}{|m(t)|}\right)\, (3+3|z_0|+2\delta)\epsilon^{-5} |z-z_0|  $$
Let $C = \left(\sup_{t\in[0,1]}{|m(t)|}\right)\, (3+3|z_0|+2\delta)\epsilon^{-5}$, and so $C$ depends only on $z_0$, $m(t)$ and the ball $U$. The desired result follows.

Do you have any recommendation on how to bound the amount $|3t-2z-z_{o}|$?

I added more details.

Let me demonstrate a general argument that also works in a more general setting.
Step 1. Suppose $z, z_0 \in \mathbb{C} \setminus [0, 1]$ are located in such a way that the line segment from $z_0$ to $z$,
$$ \gamma : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{C}, \qquad \gamma(s) = z_0 + (z - z_0)s, $$
does not intersect $[0, 1]$. Also, let us write $\Delta z = z - z_0$ and $g_t(z) = \frac{1}{(t - z)^2}$ for brevity. Then
\begin{align*}
\frac{g_t(z) - g_t(z_0)}{z-z_0}
= \frac{1}{z-z_0} \int_{\gamma} g_t'(\zeta) \, \mathrm{d}\zeta
= \int_{0}^{1} g_t'(z_0 + s \Delta z) \, \mathrm{d}s \tag{1}\label{e:1}
\end{align*}
Hence, the difference between $\eqref{e:1}$ and $g_t'(z_0)$ can be written as
\begin{align*}
\frac{g_t(z) - g_t(z_0)}{z-z_0} - g'(z_0)
&= \int_{0}^{1} [ g_t'(z_0 + s \Delta z) - g_t'(z_0) ] \, \mathrm{d}s \\
&= \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} g_t''(z_0 + rs \Delta z) (s \Delta z) \, \mathrm{d}r\mathrm{d}s. \tag{2}\label{e:2}
\end{align*}
(Remark. This is essentially Lagrange's form of the remainder.)
Step 2. Although $\eqref{e:2}$ can be used to give a bound on $\eqref{e:1}$ for arbitrary $z, z_0$ considered in Step 1, it is particularly useful when $z$ is already close to $z_0$. Since our goal is to take limit as $z \to z_0$, this does not harm the overall argument.
Indeed, suppose $\bar{B}_r(z_0)$ is the closed ball of radius $r$ about $z_0$ so that $\bar{B}_r(z_0) \subseteq \mathbb{C} \setminus [0,1]$. Since $g_t''(z)$ is continuous on $\bar{B}_r(z_0)$, it is bounded on $\bar{B}_r(z_0)$ and hence
$$ M := \sup_{\bar{B}_r(z_0)} |g_t''| < \infty. $$
Now, for $s, t \in [0, 1]$ and $z \in \bar{B}_r(z_0)$, we have the uniform bound
\begin{align*}
|g_t''(z_0 + sr \Delta z)| \leq M.
\end{align*}
Plugging this into $\eqref{e:2}$, we obtain the following bound,
\begin{align*}
\left| \frac{g_t(z) - g_t(z_0)}{z-z_0} - g'(z_0) \right|
&\leq M \left( \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} s \, \mathrm{d}r\mathrm{d}s \right) |\Delta z|
= \frac{M}{2} |\Delta z|, \tag{3}\label{e:3}
\end{align*}
for any $z \in \bar{B}_r(z_0)$. (This may look familiar to you if you studied Taylor's theorem in calculus!) Then by plugging $\eqref{e:3}$ into
$$ \frac{F(z) - F(z_0)}{z - z_0} - F'(z_0)
= \int_{0}^{1} \left[ \frac{g_t(z) - g_t(z_0)}{z-z_0} - g'(z_0) \right] m(t) \, \mathrm{d}t, $$
and letting $z \to z_0$, we conclude that $F(z)$ is differentiable at each $z_0$ and assumes the desired integral representation as in the problem.
